# byte-array as bitfield in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-fields

Is there a built-in class or something in .NET that would allow me to treat a byte-array as a large bitfield?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class.

Here is an example explaining what is going on when using a byte array:

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
BitArray myBA3 = new BitArray( myBytes );

Console.WriteLine( "myBA3" );
Console.WriteLine( "   Count:    {0}", myBA3.Count );
Console.WriteLine( "   Length:   {0}", myBA3.Length );
Console.WriteLine( "   Values:" );
PrintValues( myBA3, 8 );

public static void PrintValues( IEnumerable myList, int myWidth )
{
   int i = myWidth;
   foreach ( Object obj in myList )
   {
      if ( i <= 0 )
      {
         i = myWidth;
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
      i--;
      Console.Write( "{0,8}", obj );
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This code produces the following output.

```
 myBA3
    Count:    40
    Length:   40
    Values:
     Bit0   Bit1    Bit2    Bit3    Bit4    Bit5    Bit6    Bit7
     True   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
     Bit8   Bit9    Bit10   Bit11   Bit12   Bit13   Bit14   Bit15 ... and so on
    False    True   False   False   False   False   False   False
     True    True   False   False   False   False   False   False
    False   False    True   False   False   False   False   False
     True   False    True   False   False   False   False   False
```

Comment: Yea, I've tried using it but it seems to dome some funky stuff internally, like it's reversing the endianess or something...

Comment: @Anon - You can post another question with your issues using the BitArray class including current test and unexpected results.

Comment: @Anon: I think `BitArray` uses an `int[]` array internally, but I'm not sure how you'd know, or care, what endianness it uses. Surely from a semantic point-of-view it's just an array of `bool`.

Comment: <code>Console.WriteLine(new BitArray(new byte[] { 1 }).Get(0));</code> Prints "True" indicating(?) that its storing the byte in big-endian...

Comment: You are confused by what that is doing.  That says "Create a byte array whos first byte value is 1".  The BitArray takes that byte and says, ok value 1 means bit zero is set (true).  Bit one would be false, Bit two would be false... bit 7 would be false.  If you want to create an emtpy BitArray with one byte, do this: `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(new BitArray(new byte[1] { 0 }).Get(0));`

Comment: Okay, I expected bitArray.get(0) to return the leftmost bit of the first byte in the original byte-array and bitArray.get(bitArray.count-1) to return the rightmost bit of the last byte, but I guess their bit-numbering differs from mine. I'll just roll my own BitField-class!